# Vim-airline generating gaps at bottom

Tags: vim, vi, vundle, vim-airline

I installed the Vimair line using Vundle, as below,

Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

But the status bar is generating some of the margins at bottom. I don't know how to fix this, as I am a new learner.
A sample screen shoot is shown below.
[image: The extra margin is at the bottom in black]

Comment: Uh, what margins? It’s hard to tell from your screenshot what you mean

Comment: the above little black gaps after the command-:nohlsearch are left on the bottom of vim while using it in full-screen mode. This doesnot happen when I am using it in normal mode or not in full screen mode.

Comment: Are you using gvim or using vim inside a terminal?

Comment: I am using NeoVim. I saw that when I zoom in and out a little than the nvim window fits the Terminal size, but in the original size of my font it's not working. Is that because of Font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was having the same issue (neovim in WSL in windows terminal).
**I just clicked and dragged it down**

I also have `set mouse=a` in init.vim

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: yep this worked for me. weird

Comment: This didn't worked for me, can you mate share your vimrc file so that I can guess my missed config

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following line in your .vimrc file

`set nowshowmode`

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.